# I can't get this simple LLDB alias to work

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, alias, lldb

I want to create an LLDB alias ps, such that

```
 ps foo
```

becomes

```
 print [self foo]
```

I've been watching the LLDB talk (WWDC session 321 on iTunes), and based on that, it looks like the alias to do that should be this one:

```
command alias ps print [ self %1 ]
```

but it doesn't work.  Here I've given my app delegate a simple "count" method that returns an integer:

```
(lldb) command alias ps print [ self %1 ]
(lldb) ps count
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('AppDelegate *' and 'int')
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) print [ self count ]
(int) $6 = 2
(lldb)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems arguments (%1, %2, etc) doesn't work to alias an expression. There is a workaround by using a regular expression instead:

```
command regex ps 's/(.+)/print [self %1]/'
```

It makes an alias ps for the above regular expression:

```
(lldb) ps firstName
print [self firstName]
(NSString *) $1 = 0x06e64e20 @"John"
```

However this will last till the debug session ends. You'll have to enter it again for the next debug session. If you want your ps command to persist through debug sessions, you'll have to save it in your ~/.lldbinit file (if it doesn't exist, create one).

See [llvm blog](https://blog.llvm.org/posts/2011-04-22-regular-expression-commands/) for more deails about regex command.

Comment: I'm curious - someone actually has their ~/.lldbinit file being read by lldb? I haven't had any succes with this, either via `lldb`, `xcrun lldb` or even by Xcode.

Comment: In "command alias" the %N substitutions only work for complete argument or option values and not for parts of an argument or option value.  That limitation, and not something specific to expressions, is why the examples in this question don't work.

Comment: Here is a variant that you can use with Swift.  It works with iOS or macOS.  The prefix "Swift." is used so that you can use this when debugging a macOS view (where the default for print is to send to your printer!).   Here "mp" represent "my print":  command regex mp 's/(.+)/expr Swift.print(%1)/'