# How can I create a LLDB alias that evaluates its argument using `expression`

Tags: debugging, command, expression, alias, lldb

I'm trying to create a LLDB `alias` that evaluates an `expression` using the argument (`%1`) to the `alias`.  I've tried many, many different syntax combinations, but it seems like anything that uses `%1` in an `expression` fails to parse.

```
(lldb) version
LLDB-112.1
```

This works as expected:

```
(lldb) expr (char*) strdup(argv[1])
(char *) $23 = 0x000000010061c090 "--calc"
```

When I create an `alias` containing `%1` the example fails.

```
(lldb) command alias dup expr (char*) strdup(%1)
(lldb) dup argv[1]
error: expected expression
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

How can I create a LLDB alias that evaluates its argument using `expression`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make arguments in expression work, use **command regex** instead of alias, like this:

```
command regex dup 's/(.+)/expr (char*) strdup(%1)/'
```

For more details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690181/i-cant-get-this-simple-lldb-alias-to-work/12195214#12195214).

Answer (score 0):

I have played around with the %1 aliases quite a bit, no luck yet.  This is the closest I can come, and it's not wonderful:

[.lldbinit]

```
command alias foo expr fooFunction(
```

Then when running the debugger, the following command will in fact call the function fooFunction with input bar:

```
(lldb) foo bar)
```

That unmatched close paren is not a typo; it needs to be there to match the open paren from the alias.

Answer (score 0):

try 
command alias dup expr -- (char*) strdup( $1 );
then you'll see

```
(lldb) dup "2387987"
(const char [8]) $5 = "2387987" {
  (const char) [0] = '2'
  (const char) [1] = '3'
  (const char) [2] = '8'
  (const char) [3] = '7'
  (const char) [4] = '9'
  (const char) [5] = '8'
  (const char) [6] = '7'
  (const char) [7] = '\0'
```

for lldb build 153

Comment: It looks like the $1 refers to something different than %1.  Are you sure this is correct?  I want the first argument to the macro, rather than the first evaluated expression output.