# LLDB equivalent of GDB's macros

Tags: objective-c, gdb, lldb

I have a very useful macro defined in `.gdbinit`

```
define rc
call (int)[$arg0 retainCount]
end
```

Is there anyway to define the same macro for **lldb** ?

Comment: retainCount is useless (just a reminder)

Comment: @bbum why don't you deprecate it from SDK then?  Everyone is entitled for own opinion. I don't use ARC (at least until its major bugs will be fixed). I manage my own memory when I can. For this `-retainCount` works ok.

Comment: It is effectively deprecated in that it is no longer used in ARC, which is the recommended pattern going forward.   I have yet to see a pattern of use with `retainCount` that can't be better -- more accurately -- accomplished using other tools.  Given that `retainCount` neither reflects autorelease state nor thread state, it is growing less useful over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with the following command definition in lldb:

```
command regex rc 's/(.+)/print (int)[%1 retainCount]/'
```

Example:

```
(lldb) rc indexPath
print (int)[indexPath retainCount]
(int) $2 = 2
```

You can put that into `~/.lldbinit` (and restart Xcode).

One should think that something like

```
command alias rc print (int)[%1 retainCount]
```

should work, but as explained in [I can't get this simple LLDB alias to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690181/i-cant-get-this-simple-lldb-alias-to-work/12195214#12195214) the %1 expansion does not work with expression, and `command regex` is a workaround.

Comment: I tried to pursue 'command alias' thing too and it didn't work for me. Your solution works. Thank you very much. I want to see if others can provide more straightforward solution. If there isn't such solution, i'll mark your answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally, on architectures where function arguments are passed in registers (x86_64, armv7), lldb defines a series of register aliases that map to the register used to pass the integral values -- arg1, arg2, etc.  For instance,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  char *mytext = "hello world\n";
  puts (mytext);
  return 0;
}
```

and we can easily see what argument is passed in to puts without having to remember the ABI conventions,

```
   4      char *mytext = "hello world\n";
-> 5      puts (mytext);
   6      return 0;
   7    }
(lldb) p mytext
(char *) $0 = 0x0000000100000f54 "hello world\n"
(lldb) br se -n puts
Breakpoint created: 2: name = 'puts', locations = 1, resolved = 1
(lldb) c
Process 2325 resuming
Process 2325 stopped

libsystem_c.dylib`puts:
-> 0x7fff99ce1d9a:  pushq  %rbp
   0x7fff99ce1d9b:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
   0x7fff99ce1d9e:  pushq  %rbx
   0x7fff99ce1d9f:  subq   $56, %rsp

(lldb) p/x $arg1
(unsigned long) $2 = 0x0000000100000f54
(lldb)
```

x86_64 and armv7 both pass the first "few" integral values in registers - beyond that they can get stored on the stack or other places and these aliases don't work.  lldb doesn't currently provide similar convenience aliases for floating point arguments.  But for the most common cases, this is covers what people need.